# Copy files to their corresponding destination folders

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop

I have many files in a folder with different extensions (`.txt`, `.ascii`, `.mat`). I want to move them to the destination folder which would be same as file names.

For example:
I have files like  `a.txt, a.ascii,` `b.txt, b.ascii, b.mat`.
I want to make folder first in the name of `a` and `b`, then I want to move files `a.txt,a.ascii` to folder `a` and `b.txt,b.ascii,b.mat` to folder `b`.

I tried the code as follows. However I need an automatic way to make folder and move the files to it.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir a b
for file in $(<list.txt)
do
cp "$file" a
done
```

Comment: What is in `list.txt`?

Comment: all the files which needs to be copied to their destination folder i saved it as list.txt

Comment: Why? Are there files that shouldn't be copied?

Comment: yes only one file is there i donot want to copy

Comment: Well, have you tried `cp "${file}" "${file%%.*}"` instead of `cp "$file" a`?

Comment: No can you please suggest a solution..what i am doing is of manual way, everytime i have to make folders by mkdir ....so i am wondering if there are any automatic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this `Bash` script can do the job

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in $(<list.txt); do
    dirn="${file%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$dirn"
    cp "$file" "$dirn"
done
```

Comment: This might help: [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: This would fail on tar archives (a.tar.gz)